# How do I uninstall "nodebrew"?

Tags: node.js

Hi I'd like to uninstall nodebrew from my mac local computer.
https://github.com/hokaccha/nodebrew

I took a look at the page above but couldn't find how to unstall it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually you uninstall with npm command. Open a command line go to the folder of the project and type:

```
npm uninstall nodebrew
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, I didn't install nodebrew through npm. I used curl command to install it. curl -L git.io/nodebrew | perl - setup

Comment: The above doesn't seem to be correct, as even the OP commented that he did not used npm to install nodebrew.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any command for uninstalling (as opposed to `setup` for installation). What I did was:

1. uninstall all node versions that were installed with nodebrew:

   - `nodebrew ls` (to list all installed node versions)
   - `nodebrew uninstall <node_version>` (run this per each version of node listed with the previous command)
2. remove `NODEBREW_ROOT` environment variable set in `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`
3. remove `~/.nodebrew` if exists: `rm -rf ~/.nodebrew`
4. remove `nodebrew` itself (mine was installed in `/usr/local/var/nodebrew/`, so I did `rm -rf /usr/local/var/nodebrew`).

Above steps should do, but please let me know if I missed anything.